# gem5 to McPAT template.xml file for 2018

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, simulator, gem5

I am having lots of issues trying to convert my output from gem5 simulator into a proper xml format for input to McPAT. I am using gem5 version 2.0 which is the latest version, and I am using the 2015 McPAT release. I was given a template.xml file from someone who had a McPAT environment working in 2010 version, however, the stats and config files in gem5 have changed format. Thus, I need assistance in finding a proper template.xml that works in 2018 for the latest versions of gem5 and McPAT.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Ayymoose/gem5-mcpat-parser

This repo on github showed me exactly what I needed to do its all in the README.